# Cannot load prebuilt OpenSSL library in Android project

Tags: android, c, cmake, openssl, native

I'm trying to link the OpenSSL `.so` prebuilt files so I can use it in my native C files. In my project, I've created `native_hello.c` file and it works fine, the C code runs, but when I'm trying to

```
System.loadLibrary("crypto");
System.loadLibrary("ssl");
```

in my java code to load the OpenSSL `.so` files, the app crashes with error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcrypto.so" not found
```

I went ahead and decompiled my source apk file, and sure enough there were no `libcrypto.so` or `libssl.so` files in `lib` folder.
I'm using CMake for linking native files:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)

set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main)

add_library(lib_crypto SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_crypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.so)

# add the open ssl lib
add_library(lib_ssl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.so)

add_library(native-test SHARED
        ${distribution_DIR}/jni/native_hello.c)

target_include_directories(native-test PRIVATE ${distribution_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)

target_link_libraries(native-test
        lib_crypto
        lib_ssl)
```

In related questions one of the solutions is to use `sourceSets` in `build.gradle` but with the following code snippet the `.so` files are still missing:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is pretty easy, but I could not figure out how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are the CMakeLists.txt modifications necessary, because I think I can see the .sos in the .apk by just doing the build.gradle part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that structure of my jniLibs was something like:

```
arm64-v8a
    include
        ...
    lib
        libcrypto.so
        libssl.so
x86
    include
        ...
    lib
        ...
```

opposed to:

```
arm64-v8a
    include
        ...
    libcrypto.so
    libssl.so
x86
    include
        ...
    ...
```

Which solves initial problem.